# Can't update LiveData with new value

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am trying to update LiveData List and can't do it. The UI shows the same values from the database.
So, inside the **MainActivity** there is a function that loads data from a database and set an observer for it (if data changed). There is a button inside the activity with a listener and when I tapped the button (where I put getData(); ). I expect, when I tap on the button, it loads new random value from a database, but actually it shows the same value all the time. Could you give me an advice or help me how to solve this dead-end?! I project that it is a trivial and stupid mistake (or my ignorance). Thank you for your attention.

```
@OnClick(R.id.button)
void submitButton(View view) {
        getData();
}

private void getData(){

User userList = new User();

UserViewModel mUserViewModel;

mUserViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);

mUserViewModel.getRandom().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<User> user) {
        // Update UI
        if (user != null) {
            User userList = user.get(0);
            updateUI(userList);
        }
    }
});
}
```

**UserDao.kt**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
    fun getRandom(): LiveData<List<User>>
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public class UserRepository {

    private UserDao mUserDao;
    private LiveData<List<User>> mUser;

    public UserRepository(Application application) {
        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mUserDao = db.userDao();
        mUser = mUserDao.getRandom();
    }

    public LiveData<List<User>> getRandom() {
        return mUser;
    }
}
```

**UserViewModel**

```
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private UserRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<User>> mUser;

    public UserViewModel(Application application){
        super(application);
        mRepository = new UserRepository(application);
        mUser = mRepository.getRandom();
    }

    public LiveData<List<User>> getRandom() {
        return mUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pointless for us to try to debug since you haven't included the code of the `onClick` function of the button that you tap to update the database

Comment: Actually inside onClick I put getData();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use MediatorLiveData instead of exposing the LiveData reference directly. To refresh the random user you'd then just have to re-query the DAO which will update the value in the Activity. This can be done by making some changes as outlined below.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final UserViewModel mUserViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Other onCreate code 
        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);

        mUserViewModel.getRandom().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final User user) {
                // Update UI
                if (user != null) {
                    updateUI(user);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button)
    void submitButton(View view) {
        mUserViewModel.refresh();
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
    fun getRandom(): LiveData<User>
}
```

Repository:

```
public class UserRepository {

    private final UserDao mUserDao;

    public UserRepository(Application application) {
        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mUserDao = db.userDao();
    }

    public LiveData<User> getRandom() {
        return mUserDao.getRandom();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final UserRepository mRepository;
    private final MediatorLiveData<User> mRandomUserMediator = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    public UserViewModel(Application application){
        super(application);
        mRepository = new UserRepository(application);
        mRandomUserMediator.addSource(mRepository.getRandom(), mRandomUserMediator::setValue);
    }

    public LiveData<User> getRandom() {
        return mRandomUserMediator;
    }

    public void refresh() {
        mRepository.getRandom();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  I'm confused though:  all of the code is Java except for the Dao code that is in Kotlin?